# How to log the file name and size of file uploads

Tags: php, apache, logging, file-upload

I want to keep some statics about the files uploaded to my server, including the file name, size and response time.

I use PHP to handle the uploads in the server side (client-side is a POST form) but ideally I'd like to use Apache's logging facilities to collect the above-mentioned data. So, I'm trying to modify the default format for the access_log but I only found how to add the response time (using the %D formatter).

Is it possible to use Apache logs to monitor at least the size of POST requests and if possible the filenames of the uploaded files?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats -- see `%I`. I think this is as close as you could get.

Comment: thanks, %I looks a good solution. I guess the file size will dominate the size of the entire request.